# Suggestion with toString

Tags: java, class, tostring

I am trying to make a new program where there is one class with name GroceryItem, second with GroceryList and the third is MAIN method where all the items I want to use are.

I have make arrays to put these items in there, but when I try to print the items out, only the file name come out instead of items and nothing else, please help with that.

Here is my code:

GROCERYITEM:

```
public class GroceryItem {

    private String name;
    private int quantity;
    private double pricePerUnit;

    public GroceryItem(int quantity, String name, double pricePerUnit) {
        setName(name);
        setQuantity(quantity);
        setPriceperUnit(pricePerUnit);
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void setPriceperUnit(double pricePerUnit) {
        this.pricePerUnit = pricePerUnit;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public double getPricePerUnit() {
        return pricePerUnit;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return quantity * pricePerUnit;
    }
}
```

GROCERYLIST:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GroceryList {

    private GroceryItem item [];
    private int totalItems;

    public GroceryList() {
        this(10);
    }

    public GroceryList(int itemsOnList) {
        item = new GroceryItem[itemsOnList];
    }

    // Constructs a new empty grocery list.
    public boolean addItem(GroceryItem items) {
        boolean added = false;

        try {
            item[totalItems] = items;
            ++totalItems;
            added = true;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            added = false;
        }
        return added;
    }
    public String toString(){
        String retuurn = "";
        for (GroceryItem items : item) {
            if(items != null){
                retuurn += item.toString() + "\n";
            }
        }
        return retuurn;
    }
}
```

MAIN:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GroceryItemList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Quantity:   " + "Name:      " + "Price Per Unit:    "
                + " Total:");
        GroceryItem rice = new GroceryItem(1, "Rice", 5.00);

        GroceryItem fish = new GroceryItem(2, "Fish", 9.50);

        GroceryItem cake = new GroceryItem(3, "Cake", 5.00);

        GroceryList liste = new GroceryList(10);

        liste.addItem(rice);
        liste.addItem(fish);
        liste.addItem(cake);

        System.out.println(liste.toString());

        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------");

    }

}
```

Comment: this was the shortest example you could come up with??

Comment: "only the file name come out" - what's that supposed to mean? what's the output?

Comment: Well I mean that when I try to run the program the filename comes out instead of the items I have in the array. With file name I mean the name I have to save the file.

Comment: filename? as in with extension (eg: .java)? I doubt. don't be so sloppy. if you cannot even interpret the output, better provide it to us *as it is*.

Comment: Oi oi, don't remove your question when it's answered.

Comment: @user3012649 never remove question if you got answer. Reverted question to previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default toString method doesn't know how you are expecting the output. Hence the default behaviour is that it prints the type of the class and most possibly the address. If you are planning on printing the list you will have to write loop

This is the code you have written to override toString. You have also used incorrect valiable name for `retuurn` in loop `retur`

```
public String toString(){
    String retuurn = "";
    for (GroceryItem items : item) {
        if(items != null){
            retuurn += item.toString() + "\n"; 
            // Your variable name in your original question is retur, I'm assuming that as typo
        }
    }
    return retuurn;
}
```

Issue with this code is it uses item.toString() which you have not created so it uses default toString method, which doesn't know which data to return. use `retuurn  += item.getName()+"\n";`

Alternatively you can create a toString in your GroceryItem.java that returns what ever data you want returned. Sample code is as below.

```
public String toString(){ // inside GroceryItem.java
   return this.name; // or return this.name & ";" & this.quantity; or what ever that should be returned. 
}
```

Comment: added this to GroceryItem: public String toString() { return getQuantity() + "  " + getName() + "  " + "(" + getPricePerUnit() + " /stk)" + "  " + getCost(); BUT still the same output...

Comment: Have you corrected the variable name in your toString of GroceryList?

Comment: The variable name is retuurn?

Comment: In your original source code you have used a wrong variable name inside for loop, as i have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, I think you have misunderstood what I mentioned. I didn't mean item is not created, I meant he didn't define any toString() method in GroceryItem, which means it will be using toString of Object or what ever it's super class is.

Comment: Note that `item` is of type `GroceryItem[]`, you can't create `toString()` on that. The real issue is that `item` is not what OP wanted to use, but `items`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik  aaah... now i see. Lesson learnt ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### A lesson to learn: use sensible names for your variables. They may not matter to the compiler, but they matter a lot to *you*.

You have used unintuitive variable names in your `GroceryList`:

```
  for (GroceryItem items : item) {
      if(items != null){
          retuurn += item.toString() + "\n";
      }
  }
```

You call the array `item`, and the item in the array `items`. This made you use the wrong variable in

```
retuurn += item.toString() + "\n";
```

You should have used

```
retuurn += items.toString() + "\n";
```

Once past this error, you'll find you are still getting cryptic strings for each item because you haven't overridden `GroceryItem.toString()` so it has inherited `Object.toString()`, which behaves as you witnessed. Override `GroceryItem.toString()` with a method which produces a string to your liking.

Comment: How to do that? I mean really new to to.String...

Comment: You have already done that in `GroceryList`. Does that not prove that you know how to do it?

Comment: Well here I have done this now in GroceryItem:  public String toString() {
  return getQuantity() + "  " + getName() + "    " + "("
    + getPricePerUnit() + " /stk)" + "   " + getCost();         But still the same result...

Comment: That looks correct. You have made another kind of error now, like forgetting to recompile or another technical oversight.

Comment: Please have a look on my code and please help me with that...I have been stuck with this for so long now...Please

Comment: Sorry my friend, I am just stressed with this. Please help me with the error then...:)

Comment: You have a small typo in your `GroceryList.toString`. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Little update in toString() in the class GroceryList.In for each loop it should be items.toString()

```
@Override
    public String toString(){
        String retuurn = "";
        for (GroceryItem items : item) {
            if(items != null){
                retuurn += **items**.toString() + "\n";

            }
        }
        return retuurn;
    }
```

Also override the toString() in GroceryItem class. Hope this helps.

Comment: If you had pointed out the error in the method instead of just dumping 99% identical code, your answer would have been a lot more helpful. BTW you have my upvote for at least being right.

Comment: I am not pointing any error. It's just little change in for loop.

Comment: In your words, "correct your toString()". What needs correction save for an *error*? Furthermore, how much time do you think one needs to stare at your code before realizig there's any difference at all?

Answer (score 0):

To print the data from the items you need to override the toString method in the GroceryItem as you have done in the GroceryList.

In the GroceryItem, add the following to print the name of the GroceryItem by calling toString for it:

```
public String toString(){
    return getName();
}
```

Comment: I added this to GroceryItem: public String toString() {
  return getQuantity() + "  " + getName() + "    " + "("
    + getPricePerUnit() + " /stk)" + "   " + getCost();   BUT still the same output...